# How to create a service for automatic update?

Tags: service, updates, install4j

I've tried to create a service that calls the update application configured in the project. Therefore I used the "silent version check" template for the update process and modified the *ServiceDemo.class* from the sample to start the update application.

```
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("2529", null, true, null);
```

[image: screenshot of the updater application]

But everytime I tried to install or start the service manually or with the command line executor nothing happened.

With the following command line call the updater starts:

```
java -cp classes;.install4j\i4jruntime.jar install4j.sample.service.ServiceDemo
```

Is it necessary to add the *i4jruntime.jar* to the classpath or is it bundle with the exe-file? But I can't see anything like that for the greetings-example. Has anybody an opening for me how to create such a service?

I am using version 5.1.5.

Thanks in advance
Hardie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you cannot use a service to display a GUI. The updater would work if you run it in unattended more (with the -q flag).

To check what happens, redirect the output to a file ("Executable info->Redirection" in the launcher wizard). Also, the updater writes a log file to the temp directory that is deleted after successful completion. To keep the log file, start the updater with `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true`.

You never have to add i4jruntime.jar to launchers that are generated by install4j. That JAR file is added automatically to the class path.